# This seems bad. How should this be done? Asp.Net MVC and Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I am learning MVC and using a DropDown on my MVC app in my new User Registration form.

As for most of my screens, I have two controller methods. One for the GET (initial display of the screen), and one for the POST (When the user clicks Submit button).

Here's the code:

```
        public ActionResult UserRegistration()
    {
        SelectList list = new SelectList(SiteUserRepository.GetTimezones(), "timezone_id", "location");
        ViewData["timezones"] = list;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserRegistration(SiteUserModels.SiteUserRegistrationModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SiteUserRepository.CreateUser(model.username, model.email, model.password, model.firstname, model.firstname, model.timezone_id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        SelectList list = new SelectList(SiteUserRepository.GetTimezones(), "timezone_id", "location");
        ViewData["timezones"] = list;
        return View();
    }
```

Note that I am copying and posting code. The code for the drop down (The SelectList) is being copied. I found out that ViewData is only available for the initial request, so I needed to redo it for the Post (If the user has entered invalid data, the screen is returned ..)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be ok to return the ActionResult of the non-post Action in your case.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserRegistration(SiteUserModels.SiteUserRegistrationModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SiteUserRepository.CreateUser(model.username, model.email, model.password, model.firstname, model.firstname, model.timezone_id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return UserRegistration();
}
```

Normally, you'd want to provide some error reporting to the View though with additional data. In that case, you'd refactor your SelectList creation into a separate method to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for pointing that out. Works 100%. Will add the error checking next.